# To allign text to the rightmost region of shinydashboard :R

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny, shinydashboard

[DATA](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6Jg_Z2eVkOXX2pNZUx6NVZvSXc)

I want to add text in rightmost region in the dashboard and the text should cover all the right space column.
[image: DASHBOARD]

```
    dashboardPage(skin="yellow",
  dashboardHeader(title = "Wheat Price dashboard  ),
   dashboardSidebar(
      sidebarMenu( 
  menuItem("Punjab-khanna", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("area-chart"))
       )
       ),
   dashboardBody(
         tabItems(
       tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
          fluidPage(
            titlePanel("Wheat DARA"),
             mainPanel(fluidRow(
              box( side="right",
                           tabPanel("Price chart", dygraphOutput("plot1")

              )
            ),box(side = "right",height="250px",includeMarkdown("read.md")))

          ) )
          )
  ))

)
```

**SERVER.R**

```
   d1<-read_excel("data/Wheat data forecasted.xlsx",sheet = 1,col_names =   
       TRUE)
   #stock
   d2 <-subset(d1, select = c(1,2,3,4,5))
  #last
  d1 <-subset(d1, select = c(1,5,6,7))
  d1$`Date GMT` <- as.POSIXct(d1$`Date GMT`, format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz="GMT")
  ts1 <- irts(time=d1$`Date GMT`,value=as.matrix(d1[,2:4]))
  #stock
  d2$`Date GMT` <- as.POSIXct(d2$`Date GMT`, format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz="GMT")
   ts2 <- irts(time=d2$`Date GMT`,value=as.matrix(d2[,2:5]))

   shinyServer(function(input, output) {
   output$plot1 <- renderDygraph({   
  dygraph(ts1) %>% 
  dyRangeSelector() %>% 
  dyLegend(show = "always", hideOnMouseOut = FALSE) %>%
  dyHighlight(highlightCircleSize = 5) %>%
  dyOptions(axisLineColor = "navy", gridLineColor = "grey")
 })


  } )
```

I am not able to arrange it to the right side.

**NOTE**:I have written different text(from the image) but the task is same to arrange the text to rightmost region in dashboard

Comment: If you could share a reproducible code it'd be very easy to answer you!

Comment: @amrrs done sir, now can you help me?

Comment: Actually the above one isn't a reproducible code. Please refer this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: @amrrs Hope now you can help?

Answer (score 0):

I've added a minimal reproducible code myself. Please check. You just have to play with `fluidrow` and `column` with `width` values.

[image]

```
if(interactive()) {



## app.R ##
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
    fluidRow(
      column(

      column(
        fluidRow(
          box(plotOutput("plot1"))
        ),
        fluidRow(
          box(plotOutput("plot2"))
        ),
        width = 10
      ),

      column(
        h3(
          textOutput('text1')
        ),
        width = 2
      ),
      width = 12
      )

    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  set.seed(122)
  histdata <- rnorm(500)

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    hist(histdata)
  })


  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({

    hist(histdata)
  })

  output$text1 <- renderText({
    "Uniform: These functions provide information about the uniform distribution on the interval from min to max. dunif gives the density, punif gives the distribution function qunif gives the quantile function and runif generates random deviates."
  })



}

shinyApp(ui, server)

}
```

Source Code modified:

Please modify your dashboard input like this below. It also has plot2, since your initial question had one.

```
dashboardBody(
  # Boxes need to be put in a row (or column)
  fluidRow(
    column(

      column(
        fluidRow(
          tabPanel("Price chart", dygraphOutput("plot1")
        ),
        fluidRow(
          plotOutput("plot2")
        ),
        width = 10
      ),

      column(
        h3(
          includeMarkdown("read.md")
        ),
        width = 2
      ),
      width = 12
    )

  )
)
```

Comment: sir its looking messy, still not get the desired position.

Comment: You've modified the code like i mentioned? Could you elaborate on the messy part?

Comment: Yes i did but the space between graph and is large.Sir, i also tried different ways but in that the right space is not getting covered and the space still exist.
I am updating the current code.

Comment: can you now help me?